# Oracle job scheduler not dropping automatically

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jobs, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I have below oracle job.

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job
                   (job_name                 => m_job_name,
                    job_type                 => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                    job_action               =>    'begin Pkg_Shell.PR_WF_PROC('
                                                || p_seq_request
                                                || '); end;',
                    number_of_arguments      => 0,
                    start_date               => sysdate,               
                    repeat_interval          => null,
                    end_date                 => null,                                       
                    job_class                => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                    enabled                  => false,
                    auto_drop                => true,
                    comments                 => null
                   );
```

The above job is not dropping automatically. This job will run only once. When i went thru various sites it says

```
For auto drop,This flag if TRUE, causes a job to be automatically dropped after it has completed or has been automatically disabled. A job is considered completed if:
1.Its end date (or the end date of the job schedule) has passed.
2.It has run max_runs number of times. max_runs must be set with SET_ATTRIBUTE.
3.It is not a repeating job and has run once.
```

My job will run only once. Why my job is not Auto dropped in certain scenarios. ? We couldnt find when it is not dropped. To over come this
If i want to mention end_date like sysdate + 2 hours how to mention it ?
If i want to set max_runs or max_fails how to use that in my job. ?  Whether these two settings or anyone above will solve my problem ?

Comment: version? Did the job run at all?

Comment: Oracle 9i. Yes job is executing fine and applications are processing fine. But after execution its not dropping

Comment: 9i .... AFAIK 10gR1 was the first with dbms_scheduler.

Comment: We have created new schema in oracle 11g and tested with the same. Still we are facing the same issue. Jobs are not dropping. In production we have about 8 million jobs and which causing performance issue. Production is 10g and we are testing now in uat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so long i found the below links that helped me to fix my issue. I have used max_runs set to 1 .

dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(m_job_name,'max_runs',1);

https://community.oracle.com/thread/936850

https://community.oracle.com/message/2458833#2458833